# Regex matching a C++ class

Tags: python, c++, regex

I need to match all the C++ classes in a header file using python, each with its whole content.
I have tried a few combination (wild guesses) but didn't work, like this one:

```
'class\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*{([^{}]*)}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*;'
```

Consider that the class might include extending part, and it may contain also inner class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible to do it with regexp...

Comment: You probably need to write a parser to do this.

Comment: You are missing inheritance (e.g. `class Foo : public Bar`), `struct`s, template specializations (e.g. `template <> class Foo<sometype>`).  C++ is notorious for difficult syntax, so I'd recommend looking for a 3rd party tool.

Comment: Check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CppHeaderParser/

Comment: You can't do this entirely with `regex` because it can't handle nested brackets.

Comment: ... or brackets in comments and macros

Comment: You need to match the whole class *definition* or just its *name*? You need to know if the declaration is a *template*, a *template specialization*, a *forward declaration*? If the class is declared with `class` or `struct`? You need its fully qualified name (namespaces and outer classes) or its unqualified name only?

Comment: libclang has python bindings, I suggest you use those